# Getting Converted Product and Value from the Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to extract the Converted Product and Value from the Facebook Marketing API by using Python. I'm running the following code:

```
fields = ['ad_id', 'ad_name', 'converted_product_quantity', 'converted_product_value']
res = account.get_insights(
                        params={'time_ranges': [time_ranges],
                                'fields' : fields,
                                'breakdowns': ['product_id'],
                                'level': 'ad'})
```

I do not receive any errors. However, all the AdsInsights object I received only have the fields ad_id, ad_name, date_start, date_stop and product_id. There is no information about the converted_product_quantity and converted_product_value.

Could it be that I'm not using the appropriate combination of breakdowns and fields?